# Curl failed: Couldn’t resolve host ‘android.googleapis.com”

Tags: php, curl, push-notification

Please find below error messages. I got those when I tried to send GCM push notifications from curl command line on my computer. What is wrong with this command?

Command Line:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSyDq5WEWwiKCcDotArJXJUY6gX2AEDcxArM" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"f_0-7BAEtbc:APA91bFjLUj6cMB6n_Vz070CeaAiIpMgP3HvaS9HeptE2SMd7HMyjCDmKpmjMpODoHdezJm62WWScYp2qIt4wfIVv1xBubdYb61jleIpLlx69X2u5j1nBiJHVc3kU8fc6VGAq_dIbBZz\"]}"
```

Result:

> Curl failed: Couldn’t resolve host ‘android.googleapis.com”.

The best regards

Doeun KOCH

Comment: I ran this exact same command here and got `{"multicast_id":9143492055169576995,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1476329967432985%63e1551ff9fd7ecd"}]}`